# Programatically press a button in a website from an app in a phone

Tags: c#, html, uwp

I am creating a UWP app using c#. The app is supposed to fetch information from a website and present it to the user. I've went through the DOM of the site and managed to download the HTML of the site. But some of the information is hidden and only appears when certain buttons or selections are made on the website. Is there a way that I can programmatically go into the site, make a selection, the download the new html?

2nd Question: The app should have an fb liveChat function linked an fb page. How do I link facebook liveChat into this app? I do not have an idea in my head on how to make this work. Thank you for you help.

Comment: Can't you just call the back-end directly? This solution can be pretty tricky.

Comment: Another thought - I know I'm not helping - but it's better to post your second question as a separate question. In that question, please post the relevant code part of the things you have tried yourself.

Comment: thanks for the reply @Stefan, I will do just that. I haven't really tried any method, I've searched around but couldn't find anything maybe cause I don't know what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example for Entering text in search box and Click search button in Bing

1. Use [WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView) to do all the work

   ```
   WebView webView = new WebView();
   ```
2. Use [`InvokeScriptAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301841.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method for WebView to **use JS code**

   ```
   webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] {});
   ```
3. **Get the HTML** of the site using below code

   ```
   public LoadURI()
   {
       webView.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.bing.com/"));
       webView.NavigationCompleted += webView_NavigationCompletedAsync;
   }

   string siteHtML = null;

   private async void webView_NavigationCompletedAsync(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
   {
       siteHtML = await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.documentElement.outerHTML;" });
   }
   ```
4. **Enter text** in search box using below code

   ```
   private async void EnterTextAsync(string enterText)
   {
       var functionString = string.Format(@"document.getElementsByClassName('b_searchbox')[0].innerText = '{0}';", enterText);
       await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString });
   }
   ```
5. **Simulate click** using below code

   ```
   private async void SimulateClickAsync()
   {
       var functionString = string.Format(@"ddocument.getElementsByClassName('b_searchboxSubmit')[0].click();");
       await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString });
   }
   ```
6. Get new site's HTML using **Step 3**

Here is a Sample app for LogIn to StackOverflow: [StackOverFlow-LogIn](https://github.com/Vijay-Nirmal/StackOverFlow-LogIn)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vijay. This looks like what I want. Lemme try it out.

Comment: this is the output of your code:  _An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020101_ .       both invoke methods crash with that exception.

Comment: @Zee I have some internet problem in my computer so I can't test it. Try using WebView as an XAML element and check whether the `webView.Navigate` works. If it works then use `Button` Click event to test the `webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.documentElement.outerHTML;" });` code.

Comment: I did that, and it works fine. The problem seems to be on the EnterTextAsync & SimulateClickAsync methods with the _functionString_ part.

Comment: @Zee Did you change the functionString depend upon you URI?

Comment: I did, but it gave me errors. Then decided to try with Bing and maintain the uri, but still gave errors

Comment: @Zee It works for me. I have added a sample app in the answer check that out.

Comment: @Vijay it is now working, the problem was the spelling, it's _getElement_ not _getElements_.  also, it works with _ElementById_ rather than _ElementByClassName_ . and the bing search button doesn't seem to have a _click_, but works fine where I am using it. Thank you very much

Comment: @Zee Currect spelling is `getElementsByClassName`(Note it has `s`) and `getElementById`(Note it doesn't have `s`).