# Downloading Entire Html of a website UWP C#

Tags: c#, html, uwp, httpclient

I am making a UWP C# app which needs to download the entire html of a site. The code below is able to download the html but when I look at the DOM of the site (*F12 on chrome or Edge*) the downloaded html is missing some sections. It is not the same. I also ran the html string on the visual studio *Html Viewer*, it was indeed missing some features which I need. Is there some limitations to HttpClient or is there something that I am not doing? or maybe generally I cannot access all the sections that I see on the DOM explorer of a browser? Thank you.

```
    Private async Task<string> MakeWebRequest(string url)
    {
        HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
        http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync(url);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

Comment: If there is something added via scripts those won't show up of course unless you run the scripts.

Comment: @Zee If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44704888/7331395) answer works then consider "Mark as Answer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WebView to get HTML of the site(as I mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44692971/7331395) answer) using below code. This will get all the code(Including JS).

```
WebView webView = new WebView();
public LoadURI()
{
    webView.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.bing.com/"));
    webView.NavigationCompleted += webView_NavigationCompletedAsync;
}

string siteHtML = null;
private async void webView_NavigationCompletedAsync(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    siteHtML = await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.documentElement.outerHTML;" });
}
```

If it didn't get then try by waiting for some time and then get the HTML code

Comment: When you download the html , your string is origin html.But the chrome's html is what run the js.

Comment: @lindexi Can you give the URI? I will check it out

Comment: Just as stackoverflow ,when you login ,you will see different page.

Comment: @lindexi I have some internet problem in my computer so I can't test it. Try using WebView as an XAML element and wait until the page loaded completely. Then use Button Click event to get the HTML using `webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.documentElement.outerHTML;" })` code. Test it and let me know the result

Comment: @lindexi Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44692971/7331395) answer

Comment: @lindexi I have added a Sample app to Log into StackOverflow in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44692971/7331395) answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are no limitations on the `HttpClient` class. It is downloading the webpage at the url exactly as served from said URL's webserver. I suspect what your're encountering is related to front end Javascript frameworks that dynamically inject content *after* the initial page load. The `HttpClient` only downloads the initial page. It does not execute any javascript.

Comment: I think that might be the case, would executing the _JavaScript_ using a _WebViewer_ then re-download the html do the trick?